# Timer Display script without clear

Tags: linux, bash

I am seeking an alternative to clear, or a better way to write a timer script that I made. Essentially the script counts down from 20 minutes, then restarts from 20 minutes again. What I would like to do is avoid the blinking terminal that occurs every time clear is called, which is every second. Am I missing a better way to write this? Or am I basically stuck with clear and the blinking terminal?

```
totsecs=1200

currsecs=0

while true; do

    currsecs=$(($currsecs+1)) 

    min=$((totsecs-currsecs))
    min=$((min/60))

    sec=$((totsecs-currsecs))
    sec=$((sec%60))

    printf "%02d:%02d\n" $min $sec

    if [ $currsecs -eq $totsecs ]; then 
        currsecs=0
    fi  

    sleep 1

    clear

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a carriage return instead of a newline to return the cursor to the beginning of the same line.

```
while true; do
    (( currsecs++ )) 
    (( min = (totsecs - currsecs) / 60 ))
    (( sec = (totsecs - currsecs) % 60 ))
    printf "\r%02d:%02d" $min $sec
    (( currsecs == totsecs )) && currsecs=0
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Oh thank god. My terminal is thanking you, as well as myself.